# Can getscript run imported scripts in jquery noconflict?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, getscript

Say I am running a version of jQuery in no conflict like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">var jQuery191 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

And I had an external .js file that should be run with the no conflict version `jQuery191` and included the jQuery object of `(jQuery)` at the bottom of the script.

If I included the .js file in `getScript()` and ran it with the no conflict jQuery object:

```
(function (jQuery) {
    $.getScript("js.js");
})(window.jQuery191)
```

Would the script be run with `jQuery191` or with the original `jQuery`? Or is this logic just dumb.

Comment: In your case, it runs with the original jQuery, since you aren't ever setting the jQuery191 version to `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getScript` will just load the script and add it to the page, it won't affect the script's behavior at all. If the script accesses jQuery by it's global name, then it won't find it (due to the `noConflict` being called), and won't be able to run correctly.

If you can, I'd suggest including the script **before** calling `noConflict`, otherwise you'll have to modify the script to look for jQuery in the place you put it (`jQuery191`).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your wrapper (`(function() { ... })()`) you define the `jQuery` variabele to a copy of the `jQuery191` variable in the global scope.

That means that `$.getScript` doesn't use that variable, but calling `jQuery.getScript` works. 
Because it's an anonymous function, the `$` inside the wrapper now reference to the outer `$` variable (in this case, the `$` in the global object).
You can solve this by renaming the first parameter of your wrapper to `$`:

```
(function ($) {
    $.getScript('foo.js');
})(window.jQuery191);
```

Or by adding this in your wrapper:

```
var $ = jQuery
```

Now, both `$` and `jQuery` contains a copy of the `jQuery191` variable of the global scope.

Comment: That's correct, but it doesn't matter for `foo.js` - it will still be unaffected by the context in which it was included in the page.

Comment: However, $.getScript will get append the script to the <head>, resulting in it running in the global scope where `$` and `jQuery` are not jQuery 1.9.1